# Node in Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
}
```

I have question about this linked list code, why in the struct node there is

```
Node *next;
```

Why use the struct name for the type data instead string or int

Comment: A linked list is a linear series of node objects. In this case each node will hold data of type `int`. In order to connect these nodes you need to use a pointer. `next` will be assigned the address of another `Node` object so that we will be able to iterate from the head to the tail through those pointers.

Answer (score 4):

A linked list may look something like this:

[image]

Note that each Node has two things it's storing: the payload (or for you, `int data`), and a pointer to the next Node in the list.

What would a pointer to the next Node in the list look like? `Node *next` !

Answer (score 0):

That's what a linked list is. A node structure that includes a pointer to the next (or previous) node in the list. The idea is to efficiently insert/remove data from it.

See [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: it includes a pointer but why use the struct name, why not use like string or int *next?.

Comment: Because it includes a pointer to the *same type*, not an int*.

Comment: The structure may also contain a pointer to the next {or previous} node (structure) in the list.